# Reducer doesn't return

Tags: reactjs, redux, return, react-redux, reducers

I have an action which increments a number. But i cannot see why the value is never shown. In the container, it shows as undefined when i console the prop.
But when I console the state in the reducer itself, i can see the value.

So my problem is the reducer never returns a value. Why?

```
   //action
export const add= createAction('ADD', value => value);

//reducer
export default function addNum(state=0, action){
    switch(action.type){
        case 'ADD':
            return state+1;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

//combine reducer
const allReducers = combineReducers({
  add: addNum,
});

export default allReducers;

//container
render(){
    return(
        {this.props.num}
    )

    function mapStateToProps(state){
      return{
        num: state.add,
      }
    }

    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(GetNum);
}
```

Thank you for you help.

Comment: What if you `console.log(state)` in `mapStateToProps`? Show how you bind the reducer to your components.

Comment: it's not showing in the console

Comment: If it's not showing anything - then it has not run.

Comment: Could you tell me why it isn't working?

Comment: Have you wrapped your app in the `Provider` component, passing your store to it? e.g. `<Provider store={store}><App /></Provider>` where `store` is what you get from `createStore(...)`

Comment: are you importing the connected component as default? import x from "./x.js" and not import {x} from "./x.js"

Comment: Your `connect` statement is within the render function. Can you split your code up into file blocks and edit your post? Please include all relevant files in their entirety, this will make debugging much easier.